# Image not included in ursina program while converting from .py to .exe

Tags: exe, ursina

**Challenge**

A simple usrina program to show cube entity and some image. While running the app from the terminal, the cube entity along with the images are show perfectly.
[Here is the image while running from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp3aH.png)

Then I created a .exe file using 'auto-py-to-exe' for the same application. While running the exe file, only the cube entity is show and the images are disappeared from the screen.
[Here is the image while running the exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrMvO.png)

**Program code**

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina(title="App", borderless=False, fullscreen=False)
window.editor_ui.disable()
window.color=color.yellow

class c_1(Entity):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        parent_entity=Entity(parent=camera.ui,enabled=True)

        Entity(model='cube',parent=parent_entity,color=color.red,texture='white_cube',scale=0.2,
            position=(-0.5,0),rotation=(45,45,0))
        
        Sprite('assets/arrow.png',parent=parent_entity,scale=0.07,position=(0,0))

        Entity(model='quad',parent=parent_entity,texture='assets/down.png',scale=0.3,position=(0.5,0))
c_1()
app.run()
```

*Here you can see the files and directory of the working environment*

[Image of directory of working files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI5Hr.png)

**Folder included in compiling the program**

My_python_package\Lib\site-packages\direct

My_python_package\Lib\site-packages\panda3d

My_python_package\Lib\site-packages\panda3d-1.10.13.post1.dist-info

My_python_package\Lib\site-packages\ursina

My_python_package\Lib\site-packages\ursina

Root_folder\assets

[NOTE: My_python_package is the directory where python is installed in my system. And Root_folder is the root directory where the assets package is present]

**Expectation**
Expect to show the images in the application when it is run from exe file as the images are show when it is run from the terminal.

**Thanks**